# Simple I/O Function w/ C

Tags: c

I've just recently started trying to learn C through the tutorials on Wikibooks. I've read the beginning C pages listed [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming) and am attempting to do the exercises. I'm having a problem with the second question on loops: wherein I'm trying to make a function to output a triangle made up of lines of * characters, where the height is *2n-1* if the width is *n*. My first thought was to make a nested loop, the outer of which would create a variable for the line number, and compare it to the max height. The inner loop would create a variable that would essentially serve as the index of the * character within that particular line. My problem is I don't know how to deal with making the lines after the max width decrease in size. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void triangle(int);

int main() {
    int width;

    printf("%s", "Please enter a width for your triangle: ");
    scanf("%d", & width);
    triangle(width);
    return 0;
}

void triangle(int width) {

    for (int line = 1; line <= (2 * width) - 1; line++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < line && i < width; i++) {
            printf("%s", "*");
        }
        printf("%s", "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `printf("%s", "*");` is the same as `printf("*");` Same goes for `"Please enter ...` `printf`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: It's also the same as `putchar('*');`. Note that `printf("%s", "%");` is *not* the same as `printf("%");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void triangle(int width) {
    int line, i, rev = 0;
    for (line = 1; line < width; ++line) {
        for (i = 0; i < line && i < width; i++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (; line; --line) {
        for (i = 0; i < line && i < width; i++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! I think trying to solve it in one pair of nested loops was my problem. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

if  you want to do it in one pair of nested for loops try this:

```
void triangle(int width) {
    int i, j, height, tmp;
    height = 2 * width - 1;
    tmp = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < tmp; j++) {
            putchar('*');
        }
        putchar('\n');
        if (i < height / 2) {
            tmp++;
        } else {
            tmp--;
        }
    }
}
```